# Is there a way to record full-screen using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, recording

I was attempting to record my desktop using ffmpeg (gdigrab).
All went well with the recording until I tried to record a game (Halo2), which was the main goal.

FFmpeg wasn't recording any footage of the gameplay. Instead, it showed the desktop with a still screen of the game launching screen.

I tried to open the game in windowed mode which showed the footage, but I can't accept this as a solution. I need to be able to record the game in full-screen mode.

Is this possible with FFmpeg?

**PS**: My goal is to record any game not just the one mentioned above.

Comment: Chances are very good that it is the *game* which was blocking you from doing this, probably some sort of built-in protection that it has. If you [edit] your question to include the name of the game, someone can probably tell you for sure if that was the issue.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried OBS? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBS_Studio

Comment: @Gantendo Yes I've tried OBS, just out of curiosity it recorded the gameplay in a small window displayed on the desktop not in full screen mode After choosing the DXGI Desktop Duplication in the settings  .
However I need to implement the recording feature  programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I managed to record games with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -i desktop -f dshow -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -rtbufsize 1024M output.mkv
```